# Logstash : Trigger python script from inout or putput section

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have logstash and elasticsearch working and gets data from filebeats from different server.
I have a requirement where I want to execute a python script when a field is equal to certain value. for example if ([response] =~ /^5\d\d/) {}. i.e., when there are 500 error in log I want to execute a python script for further actions.

I have searched google , elasticforums and I have tried following but no luck so far.

I used output exec plugin to execute the code

```
exec{command=> "/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/xxxx/xxxx.py %{message}"}
```

I see empty lines as output in the logstash log.
please note that when I run

```
exec{command=> "echo %{message}"}
```

I can see output . But I cannot execute above python script.

I tried to use ruby code in input filters

```
filter{
    ruby{
        code => 'require "open3"
        message = event.get("message")
        cmd =  "python3.6 /home/xxxx/xxxx.py  #{message}"
        puts "some text"
        puts #{message}

        '
    }
}
```

No luck with it. Appreciate if anyone can help with this issue.

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: I'd guess that either (A) The script is receiving `message` in a format it's not ready for, like maybe it's a hash or somehow encoded funky, or (B) that the script isn't executable for some reason, be it permissions, the python executable, etc.   Could you try manually running the script, exactly as you have it in the `command =>` directive, using the same message that got printed when you used the `echo` command?

Comment: Yeah I can run the script manually and also I changed the script to be executable. May be I will try changing it to 777